# Ajax xml httprequest to jquery conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I'm pretty new to javascript / ajaax / jquery, but I was able to figure out the following ajax script. Unfortunately it doesn't work cross browser... as far as I can tell, not in any IE versions... I'm wondering if anyone can help me out with how to convert it to jquery? I heard that is way better than using ajax.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkRefresh(str)
{
    if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("lastCallID").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            if (document.getElementById("lastCallID").innerHTML < xmlhttp.responseText) {
                GoPopUp();  
            } else {
                setTimeout('checkRefresh()',15000)
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getnewid.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

update: I have the following code. But I still can't get it to work. I want this ajax request to be sent every 15 seconds... It calls this function getnewid.php and that function echo's out an ID... I then want the ajax to compare the id it got from getnewid.php with the "LastCallID" if the new ID is greater I want it to call this function GoPopUp. If the new ID isn't greater I want it to call itself. I initialzed this ajax request by doing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

$.ajax({
  url: "getnewid.php",
  success: function(data) {
    if (document.getElementById("lastCallID").innerHTML < data)
        {
            GoPopUp();
        }
        else
        {
            setTimeout('$.ajax()',15000)
        }
  }
});

EDIT: @Ben, this is how I've implemented it. 
(For what ever reason I can't get all the code to show up, please see attached screenshot)
http://www.screencast.com/users/bibbles10504/folders/Jing/media/7e631bd9-e9df-4cb9-ab4f-a7672bbea0a0

Comment: Umm... jquery also just encapsulates normal ajax stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>
    .......

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            initialize();
            showClock();

            (function checkRefresh() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getnewid.php',
                    success: function(data) {
                        if (parseInt($('#lastCallID').html()) < parseInt(data)) GoPopUp();
                        else setTimeout(checkRefresh, 15000);
                    }
                });
            })();
        });
    </script>

    .......
</head>

<body>
    .......
</body>
```

Comment: wow... it's that easy? I guess I can just put that If statement in place of the //do something with the response in "data". I'll have to try that out. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding what "$.ajax" is. It is not a function definition, but a function call. Your code update above won't work, because you are just putting "$.ajax()" directly into the setTimeout, with no arguments. You actually still need to include your code in a self-calling function like your original code. All "$.ajax" does is simply the ajax code and make it cross-browser. I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.

Comment: I tried what you edited, and it still doesn't work... it's saying checkRefresh is not a function in firebug.... suggestions?

Comment: @Phil, I don't know what the problem is. This code works fine for me in all web browsers, including Firefox.

Comment: Could be I'm implementing it wrong again? See my edited post, I added the snippet of code that's implemented.

Comment: @Phil, I see the problem. Yes, you are implementing it incorrectly. The function above is *self-calling*, yet you are manually calling it. When you see this structure: "(function somename(attrs) {})(attrs);" like above, it means that that you are defining a function and then immediately calling it all in one step. So, remove the manual call to checkRefresh() from your "onload", and put the whole thing above in a document ready callback. I've updated the code above to show you what I mean. While you're at it you should put your calls to initialize() and showClock() in there.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh Ok, that makes sense now. Thanks so much! Is that only for jquery or true with straight javascript?

Comment: @Phil, the "$(document).ready()" and "$.ajax()" are both jQuery-specific. The rest is straight javascript.

Comment: @Phil, also I just realized I made a typo in the above code. You have to pass the anonymous function inside the ready(), not outside like I had it. Please see the correction.

Comment: @Phil, one more minor point: When you're using jQuery, instead of writing `document.getElementById('lastCallID').innerHTML`, you can write `$('#lastCallID').html()`. I edited the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jquery for ajax $.ajax, it takes care of all that cross browser stuff for you.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/